# How to calculate current density in an Electrolysis Process?

Tags: electrolysis

I have an anode & cathode, both of $100 \times \pu{100\\mm}$ size. The process requires $\pu{450\\A/m2}$ current density. How do I reverse calculate this? Do I use the total surface area of both Cathode and Anode or just Anode? 
Please help.

Thanks

Comment: You use the cross-section, just like it were a wire.

Comment: Cross-section of both Anode and Cathode or just Anode?

Comment: Just one. Like in a wire, you would measure the cross-sectional area once, not cut the wire into many piece and add up all the areas. See https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-aabadab6ad3379dffe9a3ecb89f466ee.webp

Comment: Got it now. Thank you very much! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I use the total surface area of both Cathode and Anode or just Anode?

You use the cross-section, just like it were a wire.

> Cross-section of both Anode and Cathode or just Anode?

Just one. Like in a wire, you would measure the cross-sectional area once, not cut the wire into many piece and add up all the areas.

[image: https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-aabadab6ad3379dffe9a3ecb89f466ee.webp]

Comment: What about if anode & cathode are not of same dimensions? If I have an Aluminium sheet hardly 0.5mm thick and a Lead anode that is 3 mm thick, which cross section should I refer?

Comment: If the electrodes have different areas exposed to the electrolyte, then the electrode with smaller area would have higher current density because the current density at an electrode is simply the current divided by the electrode’s area in contact with the electrolyte.